# Is it possible in AutoMapper to copy a collection item to a specific collection based on its type?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a scenario where I have a domain model that has a collection based on an interface, meaning there could be one of two possible types. I then want to map that to a view model that is similar but contains two collections, one for each type.

Is it possible to do this using AutoMapper, so the single collection is mapped to two collections based on the type of the item in question?

I have included some example objects below with a few commented out lines, one of which shows what I tried by using the SourceType but I can't find a way for this to work.

Domain objects

```
public interface IItemType
{
}

public class ItemTypeOne : IItemType
{
}

public class ItemTypeTwo : IItemType
{
}

public class DomainModel
{
    public List<IItemType> Items;
}
```

View Models

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<ViewModelItemOne> ItemTypeOnes = new List<ViewModelItemOne>();
    public List<ViewModelItemTwo> ItemsTypeTwos = new List<ViewModelItemTwo>();
}

public class ViewModelItemOne
{
    public List<ItemTypeOne> ItemTypeOnes;
    public List<ItemTypeTwo> ItemsTypeTwos;
}

public class ViewModelItemTwo
{
    public List<ItemTypeOne> ItemTypeOnes;
    public List<ItemTypeTwo> ItemsTypeTwos;
}
```

Mapping

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dm = new DomainModel()
        {
            Items = new List<IItemType>()
            {
                new ItemTypeOne(),
                new ItemTypeOne(),
                new ItemTypeOne(),
                //new ItemTypeTwo()
            }
        };

        Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModel, ViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ItemTypeOne, ViewModelItemOne>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ItemTypeTwo, ViewModelItemTwo>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModel, ViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.ItemTypeOnes, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items); });
        //Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModel, ViewModel>().ForMember(dest => dest.ItemTypeOnes, opt => { opt.Condition(con => con.SourceType == typeof(ItemTypeOne)); opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items); });

        var vm = Mapper.Map<ViewModel>(dm);

        Console.WriteLine(vm.ItemTypeOnes.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(vm.ItemsTypeTwos.Count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by declaring how to set each property:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModel, ViewModel>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemTypeOnes, 
                 opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items.Where(i => i is ItemTypeOne))) 
      .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemsTypeTwos,
                 opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items.Where(i => i is ItemTypeTwo)));
```

Then this test will pass:

```
[TestClass]
public class TC
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void T()
    {
        var dm = new DomainModel
        {
            Items = new List<IItemType>
        {
            new ItemTypeOne(),
            new ItemTypeOne(),
            new ItemTypeOne(),
            new ItemTypeTwo()
        }
        };

        Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModel, ViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ItemTypeOne, ViewModelItemOne>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ItemTypeTwo, ViewModelItemTwo>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModel, ViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemTypeOnes, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items.Where(i => i is ItemTypeOne))) 
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemsTypeTwos, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Items.Where(i => i is ItemTypeTwo))); ;

        var vm = Mapper.Map<DomainModel, ViewModel>(dm);

        Assert.AreEqual(3, vm.ItemTypeOnes.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, vm.ItemsTypeTwos.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look now, typo fixed in the question. Was trying to use dotnetfiddle to host something but it was a bit flaky earlier.